# Java Websocket Client with PHP WebSocket Server?

Tags: html, websocket

Can a WebSocket client written in java connect with phpwebsocketserver? Or do you have to have both client and server implemented in the same language?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the definite answer, but I believe they can be different. I have worked a bit with a Flash based client communicating with a Java server and that works just fine. Hope this answer gives you enough motivation to keep looking :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.  The WebSocket protocol is still being discussed/modified.  This has resulted in some incompatibilities among different implementations (for instance, different opcode numbers).  That said, many implementations are compatible with eachother.  Once the protocol is standardized, all compliant websocket implementations will be able to communicate with eachother regardless of language.

Answer (score 0):

A socket is a socket. It doesn't matter what languages the server or client is implemented in, just as long as they can use sockets.

Comment: FYI: WebSockets are NOT standard sockets; they are created by promoting a HTTP connection by sending a specific HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what languages the clents and servers are written in. Messages are passed between the two. All that matters is that message format and header content conform to the websocket protocol.